# zone.js promises returning Unhandled Promise Rejection error even with catch blocks

Tags: angular, promise, zone

I am working on an angular environment with zone.js so all the native es6 promises have been over-written by zone-aware promises. I have 2 functions called *save()* and *onSaveCb()*

save() calls a function called *validate()* which gets the error-codes of any of the saved objects already present in the file so it is done in sync.

if hasError() returns true we return *Promise.reject()* from save() otherwise we send a save request to the backend.

Now, *onSaveCb()* function is an async/await function which has a try-catch block around *save()*.

Problem:

When Promise is rejected from *save()* function, I see console log error:

zone.js:682 Unhandled Promise rejection:  ; Zone:  ; Task: onClick Event ; Value: Error:

I tried a bunch of things with wrapping the function save in a promise and then rejecting it, but i still see the same error

```
function save() {
   let errorCode = this.validate(); // This is a sync call
   if(errorCode !== 0) { return Promise.reject(errorCode);}
   return https(url).then(function() {return true});
} 

function async onSaveCb() {
   try{
     let response = await this.save();
     alertUI(response);
     } catch (response) {
       alertUI(response);
     }
}
```

I am not sure why I am getting this message when I have clearly written error handling in the catch block. Any help here would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can import the native es6 Promise and use that instead:

`const Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;`

or

`import {Promise} from 'es6-promise;`