# Exception thrown by Firebase auth is handled in catch but still uncaught later

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing an Angular application with Firebase integration and trying to handle errors when a user logs in with incorrect credentials:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
  constructor(private router: Router, private firebaseAuthService: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.firebaseAuthService.setPersistence('session');
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuthService
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('foo'))
      .catch(() => console.log('error handled'));
  }
}
```

The catch method successfully "handles" the error, however, after that I still end up with an uncaught exception.

Console output:

> error handled

> ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: There is no
> user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been
> deleted. (auth/user-not-found).
> at createErrorInternal (index-e3d5d3f4.js:497:41)
> at _fail (index-e3d5d3f4.js:468:11)
> at index-e3d5d3f4.js:911:17
> at Generator.next ()
> at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
> at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
> at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:26)
> at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:24210:33)
> at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371:52)
> at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)

I have tried the following:

- Convert it to an observable and handle the error in the observer's error method
- Convert it to an observable and handle the error with rxjs's catchError
- use a traditional try-catch (and use await of course)

All of these approaches ended up with the same result as mentioned above (code is run in the catch block and then uncaught exception appears).

Side note: I have found a similar issue on SO ([zone.js promises returning Unhandled Promise Rejection error even with catch blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140573/zone-js-promises-returning-unhandled-promise-rejection-error-even-with-catch-blo)) and Github (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31680) as well, which describes the same error and there is a PR mentioned in the Github issue, but unfortunately not solving the problem. I have tried the zoneJS flag but the only differences the PR makes is the error is now unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block you´ll receive an exception object that can be handled and taken action, in this case I´ve build and enum to explain the error on screen:

```
.catch(error =>{
      this.material.toast(Errors[error.code], 3000, 'red full');
      if(error.code === 'auth/user-not-found')  this.router.navigateByUrl('login/register');
    })
```

Comment: The error handling in the posted code is a simplified version, but it represents my confusion as I don't re-throw the exception in the catch block.  Somehow I still get an unhandled exception.

Comment: Seems that Firebase Auth has it´s own error handler that throws the error