# Uncaught exception in NgRx Effect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I am using Firestore-Auth and NgRx for my authentication, in the store i keep the current logged-in user. For the login i created an effect to handle the async call to firebase-auth.
This is my effect:

```js
login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.login),
      switchMap((action) => this.fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.credentials.email, action.credentials.password)),
      map(() => AuthActions.loginSuccess()),
      catchError(err => {
        console.error('Exception during login: ', err);
        return of(AuthActions.loginFailure({msg: 'Login fehlgeschalfen! Überprüfe deine Email / Passwort'}));
      })), {
      useEffectsErrorHandler: false
    });
```

Albeit having the `catchError()` operator in the pipe (which is working since i see the `console.error('Exception during login')`) i get an

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-login-credentials)`

when i pass invalid credentials (testing). I can't find a way to make the `catchError()` operator to actually catch and handle the exception.

**What i tried**: First version is the one mentioned above and i also tried to catch the exception within the `switchMap` but that didn't work either:

```js
login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.login),
    switchMap((action) => this.fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.credentials.email, action.credentials.password)
      .then(() => AuthActions.loginSuccess())
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error during login: ', err);
        return AuthActions.loginFailure({msg: 'Login fehlgeschlagen! Überprüfe dein E-Mail & Passwrot'});
      }))
  ), {
    useEffectsErrorHandler: false
  });
```

Also this did not work, but that was not a surpise (more a desperate try):

```js
login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions.pipe(
        ofType(AuthActions.login),
        switchMap((action) => {
            return fromPromise(this.fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.credentials.email, action.credentials.password)).pipe(
                map(() => AuthActions.loginSuccess()),
                catchError(err => {
                    console.error('Exception during login: ', err);
                    return of(AuthActions.loginFailure({msg: 'Login fehlgeschalfen! Überprüfe deine Email / Passwort'}));
                }),
            )
        }),
    ), {useEffectsErrorHandler: false});
```

Comment: 1 question what `useEffectsErrorHandler` does ?

Comment: Probably related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77331275/exception-thrown-by-firebase-auth-is-handled-in-catch-but-still-uncaught-later